# Why I obtain this exception generating a Bitmap image object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, itext

I have some problems with this code that simply generate a graphical bitmap image (representing charts inside a PDF, but this is not important)

I have the following situation: in a class named **PdfVulnerability** I perform this statement

```
if (currentVuln.UrgencyRating > 0)
{
    img = Image.GetInstance(ChartHelper.GetPdfChart((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img) { Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER, BorderColor = new BaseColor(79, 129, 189), BorderWidth = 1, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 30, PaddingTop = 10 });
}
```

The value of **currentVuln.UrgencyRating** property is **7.5** so the debugger enter into the if body and try to perform this line:

```
img = Image.GetInstance(ChartHelper.GetPdfChart((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

So, using the debugger, I step into the **ChartHelper.GetPdfChart((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10)** execution.

Now the input paramether value is **70** (because it have cast to int the UrgencyRating value and and multiplied it by 10).

This is the body of the **GetPdfChart()** method that return a **System.Drawing.Image** object:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image GetPdfChart(int percentage)
    {
        if (percentage == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int WIDTH = 130;
        int HEIGHT = 10;

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Color.LightGreen, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));

                    using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(WIDTH * percentage / 100, HEIGHT))
                    {
                        Rectangle cropped = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                        {
                            g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropped.Width, cropped.Height), cropped, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                            //g.Save();
                            //String filename = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".png";
                            //target.Save(filename);
                            //return filename;

                            return bitmap;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This methow work fine and return a **System.Drawing.Bitmap** object to the caller that was:

```
img = Image.GetInstance(ChartHelper.GetPdfChart((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

And now my problem is that when come back and try to execute the previous operation it give me this **exception** that say: **Parameter is not valid.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you return disposed Bitmap object. The following code

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) {
   // ... some code 
   return bitmap;
}
```

is equal to

```
try {
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 return bitmap;
} finally {
   if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.Dispose();    
}
```

An image is disposed right before return. A possible solution is to make a deep copy of created bitmap so that the old one is disposed:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) {
       // ... some code 
       return (Image)bitmap.Clone();
    }
```

Comment: mmm it is not so clear for me, can you explain me better what have I to do to solve? please

Comment: I've just posted a solution.